# Jetty 9 configuration - I don't understand how it works

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I'm trying to understand how can I config jetty. I successfully created a jetty-config.xml (which I've included in my pom.xml at  declaration of jetty) which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
      <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
      <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
      <Set name="outputBufferSize">32768</Set>
      <Set name="requestHeaderSize">8192</Set>
      <Set name="responseHeaderSize">8192</Set>
      <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
      <Set name="sendDateHeader">false</Set>
      <Set name="headerCacheSize">512</Set>
    </New>

    <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8000" /></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
    </Call>

</Configure>
```

I don't understand the role of  and  tags.

For example, for my application I don't understand how to set a path for serving static files(such as images).

According to jetty 9 documentation from here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html (I run jetty with maven plugin), I need to set a tag called baseResource. This tag should "call" *org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext* (also I don't understand how this call works, I don't know even if "call" is the good keyword here), also I see in their documentation that baseResource tag belongs to webApp tag.

Please help me to understand, thank you.

Comment: You are overcomplicating things, what is your goal?   Most people have zero need to be mucking about in the server `etc/jetty-*.xml` files.  The mention of `org.eclipse.jetty.WebAppContext` hints at a desire to configure a webapp (that would be a context xml, not a server xml).  is that what you want? or just serving static files? or serving a WAR/WebApp? or some combination?

Comment: I want to setup a right environment to start learning web development with java and Spring. I found that running jetty with jetty-maven plugin is an elegant way. With jetty and maven I don't have etc/ folder(at least I can't find it's location..). My application structure contain: pom.xml, src, target. How can I give up jetty-maven and use only jetty? How should I compile the project?